# $E$ is the splitting field over $F$ for some separable $f(X) \in F[X]$ implies that $f(X)$ is separable over $\Phi(\Gamma(E/F))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, separable-extension

I'm going over the proof of Theorem 25.1 in *Abstract Algebra*, and I'm trying to understand a particular detail concerning separable polynomials. Here's the relevant portion of the theorem statement:

> Let $E$ be a finite extension of a field $F$, and suppose that $E$ is the splitting field over $F$ for some separable $f(X) \in F[X]$.

Now to the relevant snippet of the proof: Let $f(X) \in F[X]$ be as stated above. To ease notation let $K = \Phi(\Gamma(E/F))$.  The proof states that $f(X)$ is separable over $K$. Why is this? Here is the textbook's definition of a separable polynomial:

> If $f(X) \in F[X]$ we say $f(X)$ is **separable** over $F$ if every irreducible factor of $f(X)$ in $F[X]$ has distinct roots.

It's clear that $F \subseteq K$, so $f(X) \in F[X] \implies f(X) \in K[X]$. So to show that $f(X)$ is separable over $K$, we must show that if $g(X)$ is a factor of $f(X)$ that is irreducible in $K[X]$, then $g(X)$ has distinct roots. Now if such a factor $g(X)$ happens to be in $F[X]$, then we immediately know it has distinct roots (because $f(X)$ is separable of $F$). But what about when $g(X) \in K[X] \setminus F[X]$? I suspect we need to somehow use the fact that $E$ is the splitting field for $f(X)$ over $F$ (or that $K = \Phi(\Gamma(E/F))$, but I'm not sure how to proceed with this...any help would be appreciated. Apologies if this is a really dumb question.

**Edit 5/11/21: Solution**
Credit to @user363464 for this; I present here the solution in my own words.

First, I give the precise statement of Euclid's Lemma for polynomials.

> **Euclid's Lemma**: Let $F$ be a field, let $g(X) \in F[X]$ be irreducible over $F$, and let $f(X) = f_1(X) f_2(X) \cdots f_n(X)$ for some $f_1(X) f_2(X),\ldots,f_n(X) \in F[X]$. If $g(X)$ divides $f(X)$ in $F[X]$ (i.e., if $f(X) = g(X) q(X)$ for some $q(X) \in F[X]$), then $g(X)$ divides $f_i(X)$ in $F[X]$ for some $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $g(X)$ be a factor of $f(X)$ in $K[X]$ that is irreducible over $K$. By the Factorization Theorem for polynomial rings, $f(X) = f_1(X) \cdots f_n(X)$ for some polynomials $f_1(X),\ldots,f_n(X) \in F[X]$ which are irreducible over $F$. Then by Euclid's Lemma (applied to $f(X), g(X) \in K[X]$),
$$g(X) | f(X) = f_1(X) \cdots f_n(X) \implies g(X) | f_i(X) \quad \text{for some } i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$$

Therefore, $f_i(X) = g(X) q(X)$ for some $q(X) \in K[X]$. Then since $f(X)$ is separable over $F$ and $f_i(X)$ is a factor of $f(X)$ in $F[X]$ that is irreducible over $F$, we know that $f_i(X)$ has distinct roots. (This is what it means for $f(X)$ to be separable over $F$.) Now all the roots of $g(X)$ are roots of $f_i(X)$ (because $f_i(X) = g(X) q(X)$), so the roots of $g(X)$ are distinct. Hence, $f(X)$ is separable over $K$. QED.

Comment: your formulation of euclid's lemma is incorrect.  The $f_i$ need not be irreducible, only $g$ needs irreducibility

Comment: Oops. How about this: Let $f(X), g(X) \in F[X]$ and suppose $g(X)$ is irreducible over $F$. If $g(X)$ divides $f(X)$ (in $F[X]$) then $g(X)$ divides an irreducible (in $F$) factor of $f(X)$. Is that the correct statement of lemma?

Comment: No.  A correct statement of the lemma is just as you have written it in your question except removing the irreducibility of $f_i$.  Otherwise the statement is trivial since $g$ divides itself.

Comment: Ahhh, ok I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be an irreducible factor of $f$ over $K$.  By euclid's lemma for polynomials, $g$ divides an irreducible factor $h$ of $f$ over $F$.  Now $h$ has distinct roots since $f$ is separable over $F$.  So does $g$, given that $g$ divides $h$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the generalization of Euclid's Lemma to polynomials, so this is very good to know.

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question: how do we know that $g(X)$ divides a factor of $f(X)$ that is irreducible over $F$ (not just $K$)? So far I understand that:
1) We can write $f(X) = f_1(X) f_2(X) \cdots f_k(X)$, where each $f_i(X) \in F[X]$ is irreducible, and therefore,
2) if $g(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ and $g(X)$ divides $f(X)$, then $g(X) | f_i(X)$ for some $1 \leq i \leq k$. 

But I'm not seeing how this is true when $g(X) \in K[X] \setminus E[X]$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write in 2) the assumption that $g(X) \in F[X]$. If $g(X) \in F[X]$, then I agree that $g(X)$ divides some $f_i(X) \in F[X]$ where $f_i(X)$ is irreducible in $F[X]$. But if $g(X) \in K[X] \setminus F[X]$, how do we know that $g(X)$ divides a polynomial $h(X)$ that is in $F[X]$ (not just $K[X]$), where $h(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but maybe the following answers your question.  Take the decomposition $f=h_1\cdots h_n$ where each $h_i$ is irreducible in $F[X]$.  Since $g$ is an irreducible factor of $f$ in $K[X]$, $g$ divides the product $h_1\cdots h_n$.  Euclid's lemma asserts an irreducible cannot divide a product without dividing a factor.  Thus, $g$, as an irreducible divisor of the product $h_1\cdots h_n$, must divide one of $h_1$, $\dots$, $h_n$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still confused about the Euclid's lemma step. I've edited my post in an attempt to explain my confusion.